# Unable to consume spring boot rest service from different network. But, I am able to consume the api from same machine

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I built a rest service using spring boot and spring data jpa rest. The consumption of the rest api is working fine in same machine. But, when I tried access the same service from different network, it's not working.

Comment: is network access in enabled between two machines?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to put `"@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:9000")"` on above the function in the controller.

For reference 
https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/